# Process 'command 'docker'' finished with non-zero exit value 127

Tags: linux, docker, gradle

I've got a Dockerfile where I need to install tzdb in docker image

```
FROM xxx.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal

ARG DISTRIB_DIRECTORY

LABEL Team="XXX"

COPY  ${DISTRIB_DIRECTORY} /usr/app/

RUN mkdir tzdb &&\
    cd tzdb &&\
    address=$(pwd) &&\
    wget https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzcode-latest.tar.gz &&\
    wget https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdata-latest.tar.gz &&\
    tar xzfv tzcode-latest.tar.gz &&\
    tar xzfv tzdata-latest.tar.gz &&\
    make rearguard_tarballs &&\
    wget https://cdn.azul.com/tools/ziupdater1.1.1.1-jse8+7-any_jvm.tar.gz?_gl=1*7ygfs9*_ga*NzYxMzQ2MjAzLjE2OTExNDUwMDg.*_ga_42DEGWGYD5*MTY5MTE0NTAwNy4xLjAuMTY5MTE0NTAwNy42MC4wLjA. &&\
    sudo java -jar ziupdater-1.1.1.1.jar -l file://$address/tzdataVERSION-rearguard.tar.gz &&\
    java_address=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))) &&\
    sudo chmod 644 $java_address/lib/tzdb.dat
USER myuser
```

When I run it I got an error

```
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir tzdb &&    cd tzdb &&    address=$(pwd) &&    wget https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzcode-latest.tar.gz &&    wget https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tzdata-latest.tar.gz &&    tar xzfv tzcode-latest.tar.gz &&    tar xzfv tzdata-latest.tar.gz &&    make rearguard_tarballs &&    wget https://cdn.azul.com/tools/ziupdater1.1.1.1-jse8+7-any_jvm.tar.gz?_gl=1*7ygfs9*_ga*NzYxMzQ2MjAzLjE2OTExNDUwMDg.*_ga_42DEGWGYD5*MTY5MTE0NTAwNy4xLjAuMTY5MTE0NTAwNy42MC4wLjA. &&    sudo java -jar ziupdater-1.1.1.1.jar -l file://$address/tzdataVERSION-rearguard.tar.gz &&    java_address=$(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))) &&    sudo chmod 644 $java_address/lib/tzdb.dat' returned a non-zero code: 127
Execution failed for task ':docker'. org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'docker'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

Where could be a problem?

Comment: You need to install `default-jdk make tar wget` before your `RUN`

Comment: Something in the very long `RUN` command didn't work.  Try breaking it up into separate `RUN` commands and identifying which one fails.  In addition to `java` being missing (do you need it, or just to unpack those two tar files?) the two appearances of `sudo` will cause trouble, and you can just delete the word `sudo` in those commands (you're already running as root).